# Handling a dynamic sql query in Psycopg2 with multiple WHERE condition

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to execute a sql query dynamically with multiple `WHERE` conditions. the query is as below

```
query = """SELECT * FROM UBO_EXCEPTION
WHERE reg_nb = %s
AND   return_date = %s::date
AND   data_type = %s
ORDER BY db_timestamp
LIMIT 1"""
```

The method that run the query is as below:

```
cursor.execute(query, param)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Sample `param` value  is as below, there are 4 records in it:

```
(('00246102', datetime.date(2024, 3, 25), 'UKNI'), ('00246107', datetime.date(2024, 3, 25), 'SH01'), ('00246109', datetime.date(2024, 3, 25), 'CS01'), ('00246101', datetime.date(2024, 3, 25), ''))
```

This is giving an error:- `not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

I tried a minor change in the method, which is as below:

```
cursor.execute(query, (param,))
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

This gave me:- `tuple out of index error`

I am not sure, what to do next. Any suggestion is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: You set up 3 `%s` parameter placeholders and then gave it 4.

Comment: There are 3 parameters, and they are as below:

```
'00246102' ,
datetime.date(2024, 3, 25) ,
'UKNI'
```
Not sure, why you think its 4

Comment: *"Sample param value is as below:"* lists a 4-element tuple and each of its elements is a 3-element tuple. I think the code you showed attempts to pass that whole thing into the query, so your first `%s` gets replaced by a string representation of the first 3-element tuple, 2nd by the 2nd, 3rd by the 3rd, and then it fails because it's left with the 4th, unused. What happens if you try to `cursor.execute(query, param[1])`? Maybe you wanted to [`cursor.executemany(query, param)`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany)

Comment: I tried  cursor.executemany(query, param). This also threw the same error - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Just now tried cursor.execute(query, param[1]) also, same error

Comment: Since you are casting the second tuple element to `date` in Postgres, replace `datetime.date(2024, 3, 25)` with a formatted string, `'2024-03-25'` or `datetime.date(2024, 3, 25).isoformat()`

Comment: @Stefanov.sm, it will work either way. `cur.mogrify("select * from cell_per where ts_insert < %s::date", [date(2012, 12, 31)]) "select * from cell_per where ts_insert < '2012-12-31'::date::date"`. It  looks funny but it works.

Comment: This `not all arguments converted during string formatting` says you are providing more arguments then placeholders. So either your query string is not what you think it is or the tuples you are using for arguments have more values then you think they have.

Comment: I tried all possible trial and error. `cursor.executemany(query, param)`  with param data passed as - `('00246102', '2024-03-25', 'UKNI')`  (date format changed) is giving a better output. 

The better output is not actual data from table. But another error - `ProgrammingError: no results to fetch`. However, there is data is present in table.

Is there any reason why, the query is unable to fetch data?

Comment: **DON'T put your code in the comments update your question text**.  When you do use a complete example.